# Add borders to a videostream with GStreamer 0.10

Tags: video, border, gstreamer

I created a picture mosaic with videomixer2, and I want to add borders around one of my pictures. I tried to use the videoscale "add-borders" property, but it doesn't work.

Here is my pipeline :

```
gst-launch videomixer2 sink_0::ypos=200 sink_0::xpos=200 \
                   sink_2::xpos=200 \
                   sink_3::xpos=400 \
                   sink_4::ypos=200 \
       name=mixer ! \
    ffmpegcolorspace ! xvimagesink \
    uridecodebin uri=http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2d/Nostalgie_logo_simple.png/120px-Nostalgie_logo_simple.png ! \
            videoscale ! ffmpegcolorspace ! imagefreeze !  \
            textoverlay font-desc="Sans 24" text="Nostalgie" valign=top shaded-background=true ! \
            textoverlay font-desc="Sans 24" text="PLAYING" valign=bottom shaded-background=true ! \
            "video/x-raw-yuv, format=(fourcc)AYUV, width=200, height=200" ! mixer. \
    uridecodebin uri=http://www.logotheque.fr/6396-2/logo+RMC+INFO.jpg ! \
            videoscale ! ffmpegcolorspace ! imagefreeze ! \
            textoverlay font-desc="Sans 24" text="RMC" valign=top shaded-background=true ! \
            "video/x-raw-yuv, format=(fourcc)AYUV, width=200, height=200" ! mixer. \
    uridecodebin uri=http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/fr/1/14/Logo_vibration.JPG ! \
            videoscale add-borders=true ! ffmpegcolorspace ! imagefreeze ! \
            textoverlay font-desc="Sans 24" text="Vibration" valign=top shaded-background=true ! \
            "video/x-raw-yuv, format=(fourcc)AYUV, width=200, height=200" ! mixer. \
    uridecodebin uri=http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b4/France_Inter.png ! \
            videoscale ! ffmpegcolorspace ! imagefreeze ! \
            textoverlay font-desc="Sans 24" text="France Inter" valign=top shaded-background=true ! \
            "video/x-raw-yuv, format=(fourcc)AYUV, width=200, height=200" ! mixer. \
    uridecodebin uri=http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/64/France_Info.png/120px-France_Info.png ! \
            videoscale ! ffmpegcolorspace ! imagefreeze ! \
            textoverlay font-desc="Sans 24" text="France Info" valign=top shaded-background=true ! \
            "video/x-raw-yuv, format=(fourcc)AYUV, width=200, height=200" ! mixer.
```

The "add-borders" property is placed on the third source. What am I missing ? And if it isn't possible using videoscale, how can I add borders around my videostream ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can change output size of videomixer2 if you add "video/x-raw-yuv, width=(int)650, height=(int)450, framerate=(fraction)25/1" your ouput is bigger so after with xpos and ypos you have a border.

videomixer2 ... ! "video/x-raw-yuv, width=(int)650, height=(int)450, framerate=(fraction)25/1" ! ffmpegcolorspace ! xvimagesink

Comment: You mean having a large window with the same video size and move the videos with xpos and ypos to create a border artificially ?
There is no way to create a border around a video "cleanly" ?

Comment: I htink you could with videobox also